# MySQL: Group Values

Tags: mysql, group-by

Say I have a table `Connections` with format `[logID, user, time]`

An example set be:

```
| logID |  user |  time 
|-----------------------
|  91   | terry | 12:55:00  <--- Last by user
|  90   | terry | 12:54:26
|  89   | nami  | 12:52:12  <--- Last by user
|  88   | terry | 12:50:50  <--- Last by user
|  87   | terry | 12:49:21
|  86   | terry | 12:48:16
|  85   | terry | 12:46:07
|  84   | nami  | 12:31:22  <--- Last by user
|  83   | nami  | 12:30:30
|  82   | nami  | 12:29:26 
|  81   | terry | 12:27:12  <--- Last by user
```

The desired query should GROUP the user column **whenever it changes** and *select the last timestamp* by that user:

```
| logID |  user |  time 
|-----------------------
|  91   | terry | 12:55:00  <--- Last by user
|  89   | nami  | 12:52:12  <--- Last by user
|  88   | terry | 12:50:50  <--- Last by user
|  84   | nami  | 12:31:22  <--- Last by user
|  81   | terry | 12:27:12  <--- Last by user
```

I've been playing around with GROUP BY, but haven't gotten anywhere...

Comment: Can there be any gaps in logID distribution? I mean, can we always say that previous row for the row with logID = n _always_ has logID = n - 1?

Comment: sorry didn't see this comment -- answer is yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be using user variables:

```
SELECT   logID, @lastuser:=user AS user, time
FROM     mytable, (SELECT @lastuser:=NULL) init
HAVING   NOT @lastuser<=>user
ORDER BY time DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe097/1/0).

Comment: +1, because this answer doesn't need the gapless logID column at all. ) Might be a bit slower, though?

Comment: Chosen answer for compactness

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there's no such gaps, one can use something of...

```
    SELECT a.logID, a.user, a.time
      FROM Connections a
 LEFT JOIN Connections b ON b.logID = a.logID + 1
     WHERE a.user <> b.user 
        OR b.user IS NULL
  ORDER BY a.logID desc;
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f030/11) to play with.